# Locating the Nearest Junctions Outside a Specific Area Using Network Analyst

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-server

I'm seeking guidance on how to use ArcGIS tools to identify and determine the closest road junctions that are situated outside a specified geographic area.  These junctions should be part of the network and can be used to enter the area (not closed, not one way etc..)

The objective is to find junctions that provide access to the area while ensuring they are not located within the area itself.

This information will be invaluable for managing vehicle access control, planning road closures, or making informed decisions related to the specified region.

The question pertains to the process of utilizing Network Analyst to identify and map these access points efficiently.

Used software can be ArcPRO and/or ArcGIS Server